# When combining multiple queries into one how do you sum columns together

Tags: mysql, sql, union-all

I'm trying to calculate League Standings from a table of Matches.

```
+----------------------------------+
|              Matches             |
+----------------------------------+
| id                               |
| league_id (FK League)            |   
| season_id (FK Season)            |
| home_team_id (FK Team)           |
| away_team_id (FK Team)           | 
| home_score                       |
| away_score                       |
| confirmed                        |
+----------------------------------+
```

I can correctly calculate the Home League Standings using this query:

```
SELECT team.name, home_team_id AS team_id,
    COUNT(*) AS played,
    SUM((CASE WHEN home_score > away_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS won,
    SUM((CASE WHEN away_score > home_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS lost,
    SUM((CASE WHEN home_score = away_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS drawn,
    SUM(home_score) AS goalsFor,
    SUM(away_score) AS goalsAgainst,
    SUM(home_score - away_score) AS goalDifference,
    SUM((CASE WHEN home_score > away_score THEN 3 WHEN home_score = away_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS points
FROM matches
INNER JOIN team ON matches.home_team_id = team.id
WHERE league_id = 94
    AND season_id = 82
    AND confirmed IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY home_team_id
ORDER BY POINTS DESC;
```

[image]

And Away League Standigns using this query:

```
SELECT team.name, away_team_id AS team_id,
    COUNT(*) AS played,
    SUM((CASE WHEN away_score > home_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS won,
    SUM((CASE WHEN home_score > away_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS lost,
    SUM((CASE WHEN home_score = away_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) as drawn,
    SUM(away_score) AS goalsFor,
    SUM(home_score) AS goalsAgainst,
    SUM(away_score - home_score) AS goalDifference,
    SUM((CASE WHEN away_score > home_score THEN 3 WHEN away_score = home_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS points
FROM matches
INNER JOIN team ON matches.away_team_id = team.id
WHERE league_id = 94
    AND season_id = 82
    AND confirmed IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY away_team_id
ORDER BY points DESC;
```

[image]

But combining these two queries using UNION ALL I'm not getting correct result

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT team.name, home_team_id AS team_id,
        COUNT(*) AS played,
        SUM((CASE WHEN home_score > away_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS won,
        SUM((CASE WHEN away_score > home_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS lost,
        SUM((CASE WHEN home_score = away_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS drawn,
        SUM(home_score) AS goalsFor,
        SUM(away_score) AS goalsAgainst,
        SUM(home_score - away_score) AS goalDifference,
        SUM((CASE WHEN home_score > away_score THEN 3 WHEN home_score = away_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS points
    FROM matches
    INNER JOIN team ON matches.home_team_id = team.id
    WHERE league_id = 94
        AND season_id = 82
        AND confirmed IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY home_team_id
UNION
    SELECT team.name, away_team_id AS team_id,
        COUNT(*) AS played,
        SUM((CASE WHEN away_score > home_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS won,
        SUM((CASE WHEN home_score > away_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS lost,
        SUM((CASE WHEN home_score = away_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) as drawn,
        SUM(away_score) AS goalsFor,
        SUM(home_score) AS goalsAgainst,
        SUM(away_score - home_score) AS goalDifference,
        SUM((CASE WHEN away_score > home_score THEN 3 WHEN away_score = home_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS points
    FROM matches
    INNER JOIN team ON matches.away_team_id = team.id
    WHERE league_id = 94
        AND season_id = 82
        AND confirmed IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY away_team_id
) x 
GROUP BY team_id
ORDER BY points DESC;
```

[image]

This should be the expected result:

[image]

Any idea on what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Update 1:

Trying out Dans query doesn't work:

select team.name, HomePoints + AwayPoints points
from team join (
    select team.id, 
        sum(case when home.home_score > home.away_score then 3
            when home.home_score = home.away_score then 1 else 0 end) HomePoints,
        sum(case when away.away_score > away.home_score then 3 else 0 end) AwayPoints
    from team 
    join matches home on team.id = home.home_team_id
    join matches away on team.id = away.away_team_id
    WHERE home.league_id = 94
        AND home.season_id = 82
        AND home.confirmed IS NOT NULL 
    group by id
) temp on team.id = temp.id
order by points desc;

I get this result:

[image]

Comment: Your expected result includes fields that are not being selected.

Comment: @DanBracuk When looking at the expected result please only take into consideration "P W ... PTS" part. This picture is from an old way I was using where I have a LeagueStanding table and updated the values after every match with PHP, but new features I am planning has forced me to use a database query instead.

Comment: Give me a moment and I'll update the query to show names too.

Answer (score 1):

You might wanna use a JOIN instead of a UNION.
You are using a GROUP BY on the team_id after using the UNION on the subqueries that both have a team_id.
That is not going to work... If you just use the join, you can even leave out the group by.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this sort of approach.  I'm just going to do the points.  The logic is the same for the other stuff you want.

```
select TeamName, HomePoints + AwayPoints points
from team join (
select team_id
, sum(case when home.home_score > home.away_score then 3
when home.home_score = home.away_score then 1 else 0 end) HomePoints
, sum(case when away.away_score > away.home_score then 3
when away.home_score = away.away_score then 1 else 0 end) AwayPoints
from team join matches home on team.team_id = home.home_team_id
join matches away on team.team_id = away.away_team_id
where blah blah blah
group by team_id
) temp on team.team_id = temp.team_id
order by points desc
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it out in the morning.

Comment: Tried out this query but it's giving me way too many points (e.g. 264 for team in first position)

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what's going on, but don't have a MySQL install to test it.

When you do a group by query, every column that *isn't* part of the group by clause *must* be an aggregate function (SUM, MAX, etc). Most DB engines will give you an error if you don't so this; MySQL tries to be helpful? by picking a random row instead.

tl;dr Your outer select needs a bunch of SUMs rather than just selecting *.

Comment: It picks whatever value it encounters first on disk.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT team.name, 
       team_id AS team_id,
       COUNT(*) AS played,
       SUM((CASE WHEN team_score > other_team_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS won,
       SUM((CASE WHEN team_score < other_team_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS lost,
       SUM((CASE WHEN team_score = other_team_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS drawn,
       SUM(team_score) AS goalsFor,
       SUM(other_team_score) AS goalsAgainst,
       SUM(team_score - other_team_score) AS goalDifference,
       SUM((CASE WHEN team_score > other_team_score THEN 3 
                 WHEN team_score = other_team_score THEN 1 
                 ELSE 0 END)) AS points
FROM
    (
        -- LIST TEAM STATS WHEN PLAYED AS HOME_TEAM
        SELECT 
             id                               
             league_id
             season_id
             home_team_id as team_id,
             home_score   as team_score,
             away_score   as other_team_score, 
             confirmed 
        FROM    matches
        UNION ALL
        -- LIST TEAM STATS WHEN PLAYED AS AWAY_TEAM
        SELECT 
             id                               
             league_id
             season_id
             away_team_id as team_id,
             away_score   as team_score,
             home_score   as other_team_score, 
             confirmed 
        FROM matches
    ) matches
INNER JOIN team ON matches.team_id = team.id
WHERE league_id = 94
    AND season_id = 82
    AND confirmed IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY team.name, team_id
ORDER BY POINTS DESC;
```